# ReSharper auto-complete enums

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.0

In ReSharper 6.1, when I want to autocomplete something like `EnableCap.LineSmooth`, I get something like this:

[image]

The problem is, because it displays the *full* name of enum + enum options, I can't just type "En" + [Tab] to autocomplete "EnableCap." and then start typing "Li", because as soon as I hit tab the first time, it tries to auto-complete the whole thing, with an option I don't want. So now I have to type the entire "EnableCap." before I can start filtering down the options I actually want.

So my question is, how do I either
a) Tell resharper to only display autocompletes up to the dot
b) Is there a different hotkey other than tab to only complete the first bit?

Answer (score 3):

You're complaining that they made it more efficient?

You don't *need* to type `En` [Tab] `Li` [Tab] anymore. You can just type `Li` [Tab].

Granted, you have to unlearn your old habits. But the new way is faster.

Comment: Time out a second. I didn't know I could *start* with "Li". If I knew *that* then maybe I wouldn't be complaining!

Comment: @Mark, sure, you can type something from the middle of the identifier. Part of the improved CamelHumps searching, which I think they added in v5 and refined further in v6. I think you have to start on something that's a capital letter in the actual identifier, but yeah, you could just as well type `smooth` or `li` or `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> shows the enum
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> shows the members